# Нестандартное предложение.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Это глупый текст из одной песни.

**Ночью повезла свои новые груди,попу, зубы и губы ()ты()шокировать клубы.**

Представим,что мы берем интервью,в котором проскальзывает это предложение.И перепечатываем его дословно.
Поэтому предложение  будет  составлено именно так.

**Ты** выделяется знаками?
Там уместнее бы смотрелось **Чтобы**,но такое предложение.
Как вообще в таких нестандартных случаях ставятся знаки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никаких запятых помимо проставленных тут не требуется .
Грамматически это предложение вполне корректно, имеет место инверсия, но здесь это стилистический прием, грамматика от того не страдает.

Вот если бы фраза была действительно некорректна грамматически (вернее всего - синтаксически), то знаки пришлось бы ставить по воле автора, поскольку правила правописания далеко не всегда оговаривают все случаи возможных грамматических ошибок.